# Как исправить баг в выпдпющем меню?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Все привет я хотел спросить у меня есть выпадаюший меню я все реализовал в Jquery простыми кликам и с добавлением классами! У меня проблема такая мои подменю не должны открываться сразу ну не сразу а если ты откроешь по очереди меню станет очень длиннм а мне нужен то что когда ты открыл 1 подмнею и хочешь открыть 2ю не закрывая 1ю потом когда кликнешь вторю должень закрыиться 1 подменю! И все Спасибо)

Мой Jquery код -

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.icon1').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu1').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon2').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu2').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon3').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu3').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon4').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu4').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon5').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu5').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon6').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu6').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon7').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu7').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 11.2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateY(-0.5px);
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.164);
}
.sub_menu {
    width: 284px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(230, 225, 225);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

.active {
    display: block;
}

.rotate {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

#main_link {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#link_wrapper {
    width: 284px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(230, 225, 225);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#link_wrapper {
    width: 284px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 225, 225);
}
#sub_icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#sub_link_wrapper {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#sub_menu_link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 284px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon1" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu1">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon2" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu2">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon3" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu3">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon4" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu4">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon5" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu5">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon6" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu6">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon7" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu7">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. Много раз для разнык картинок использовать `id="icon"` - неверно. Идентификатор на то и идентификатор, чтобы нигде не повторяться в рамках одной страницы. Как нельзя много раз писать и  `id="main_link"`. Короче, везде, где у вас повторяются id - их надо заменить на классы.

Comment: 2. А вот `class="icon1"` и так далее, раз они уникальны, следовало бы переделать на id. А потом уж исправлять скрипт.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Раздельный показ блоков по клику на кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1196505/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 0):

Как я написал выше в комментариях, классы и id вы использовали неправильно. Самый простой вариант реализовать всё вот так:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // функцию пишем одну для всех пунктов меню
  $(".icon").on("click", function(e) {
    // сначала убираем класс "active" у всех sub_menu
    $(".sub_menu").removeClass("active");
    // а теперь назначаем его для конкретного нажатого
    $(e.target).closest("li").children(".sub_menu").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 11.2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateY(-0.5px);
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.164);
}
.sub_menu {
    width: 284px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(230, 225, 225);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

.active {
    display: block;
}

.rotate {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.main_link {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.link_wrapper {
    width: 284px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(230, 225, 225);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.sub_icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.sub_link_wrapper {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.sub_menu_link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 284px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="wclassth=device-wclassth, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><div class="link_wrapper"><a class="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img class="icon" id="icon1" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu1">
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div class="link_wrapper"><a class="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img class="icon" id="icon2" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu2">
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div class="link_wrapper"><a class="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img class="icon" id="icon3" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu3">
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div class="link_wrapper"><a class="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img class="icon" id="icon4" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu4">
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div class="link_wrapper"><a class="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img class="icon" id="icon5" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu5">
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div class="link_wrapper"><a class="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img class="icon" id="icon6" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu6">
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div class="link_wrapper"><a class="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img class="icon" id="icon7" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu7">
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_menu_link"><img class="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a class="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div class="link_wrapper"><a class="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Как можете видеть, нет необходимости писать отдельную функцию для каждого отдельного подменю. Нужно писать одну функцию, чтобы она работала сразу для всех элементов такого типа, раз они работают одинаково. Первым делом при нажатии на любую иконку мы убираем класс "active" у всех подменю, а потом назначаем его только нажатому.

Есть нюанс. Приведённый мною скрипт не реагирует на повторное нажатие той же иконки - не закрывает текущее подменю при повторном нажатии. Если это необходимо - следует доработать скрипт. Кроме того, я писал его "на скорую руку", возможно, `$(e.target).closest("li").children(".sub_menu").addClass("active");` не самый оптимальный вариант обращения к нужному подменю, но это первое, что пришло в голову.

Comment: @UModeL Имеете право, но что конкретно вам не любо? Как по мне - вполне рабочий пример. Разве нет?

Comment: @UModeL Пардон, автозаменой менял, не перепроверил. Сейчас исправлю. Спасибо.

Comment: @UModeL Собственно, поправил. Там всё проще. В оригинале у человека были попутаны id и классы. В большинстве мест я поменял их, а в дочерних списках - не заметил. Спасибо, что подсказали.

Answer (score -1):

Да у меня получилось но все же не лопо получилось)
Спасибо за ответ)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.icon1').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu1').toggleClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu3').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu4').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu5').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu2').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu7').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon2').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu2').toggleClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu1').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu3').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu4').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu5').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu6').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu7').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon3').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu3').toggleClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu4').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu5').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu6').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu7').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu2').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu1').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon4').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu4').toggleClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu5').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu6').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu7').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu1').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu2').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu3').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon5').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu5').toggleClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu4').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu6').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu7').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu1').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu2').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu3').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon6').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu6').toggleClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu5').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu4').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu7').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu1').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu2').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu3').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('.icon7').click(function (e) {
        $('#sub_menu7').toggleClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu5').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu4').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu6').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu1').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu2').removeClass('active');
        $('#sub_menu3').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 11.2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateY(-0.5px);
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.164);
}
.sub_menu {
    width: 284px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(230, 225, 225);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

.active {
    display: block;
}

.rotate {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

#main_link {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#link_wrapper {
    width: 284px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(230, 225, 225);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#link_wrapper {
    width: 284px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 225, 225);
}
#sub_icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#sub_link_wrapper {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#sub_menu_link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 284px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon1" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu1">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon2" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu2">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon3" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu3">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon4" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu4">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon5" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu5">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon6" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu6">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a><img id="icon" class="icon7" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu7">
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                    <li id="sub_menu_link"><img id="sub_icon" src="/img/arrow.svg" alt=""><a id="sub_link_wrapper" href="#">Тестовое слово2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div id="link_wrapper"><a id="main_link" href="#">Тестовое слово</a></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы совсем не читали, что написано выше? 1. Нельзя на одной странице многократно использовать одни и те же id. 2. В программировании имеется принцип: DRY - Don't repeat yourself, переводится как "Не повторяйтесь". Не пишите один и тот же по-сути код многократно. Зачем вам 7 одинаковых по сути функций? А если пунктов меню будет 274? Будете делать функцию для каждого? Я написал вам ответ, в котором одна функция работает сразу для всех элементов с подменю. К тому же исправил косяки с классами и id. Потрудитесь хотя бы прочесть.

Comment: Можете помочь оптимизировать

Comment: Я написал вам ответ. В нём исправил косяки с использованием id и class, а также написал функцию, одну и сравнительно короткую. которая сразу работает со всеми пунктами вашего меню. Испробуйте это.